# What is the best practice / best place for enabling/disabling site-wide admin functionality

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, django-admin-actions

Situation: I have a Django project with multiple applications, each of which have one or more models. I have added custom [admin actions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#admin-actions) for some of the models and got the "Delete selected" action for free. I want to disable this for all models in all applications.

I'm aware how to [disable the "Delete selected"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#disabling-a-site-wide-action) action for the whole project, i.e. by using

```
admin.site.disable_action('delete_selected')
```

but I simply don't know where to put it. I've put it in the `admin.py` file of one application and that definitely works, but that bugs me as (in my opinion) a site-wide change, also affecting other applications, shouldn't be caused by the admin configuration of a single application. I was hoping to find some way to have a "project-level" `admin.py` file, but it seems that only [fully customizing the AdminSite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#customizing-the-adminsite-class) will do the trick, which I think is a bit overkill if I only want to disable the "delete_selected" action globally.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's somewhat up to you, but to do that where you are already importing the necessary module would make sense.

It's likely you could do this in your project `urls.py`, and taking one of mine as an example you'd do;

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import re_path, path, include
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from django.views.i18n import JavaScriptCatalog


try:
    admin.site.disable_action('delete_selected')
except KeyError:
    pass


urlpatterns = [

    path(
        'jsi18n/',
        cache_page(60 * 60, cache='pages')(
            JavaScriptCatalog.as_view()
        ),
        name='javascript-catalog'
    ),
    path(
        'admin/',
        admin.site.urls
    )
]
```

I've wrapped it in a `try/except` because I've seen a `KeyError` when testing this.

Comment: I actually did think about (ab)using `urls.py` for this as that indeed already contains the URL pattern for the admin interface, so I'll go with that solution. Thanks.